# Can UserPrincipalName be the User's Email Address?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've been setting up a test Azure AD service on Azure and a multi tenanted MVC app that uses it.

When trying to create a new user using the Azure AD Graph Client, errors about the UserPrincipalName being invalid started to appear.  Once I changed the email address to one that matched my domain in Azure, everything worked and I could programmatically create new users.

However this isn't really what I need.  I would like users to be able to register with the system using their own email address as the user name (their email address could be anything).  Have I hit a brick wall regarding what is possible using Azure AD, is this an inbuilt restriction (design feature) or am I missing something?

Does anyone know how I can use Azure AD and have user's use their own email address as their user/login name?

Comment: Have you tried Azure AD b2c? See the [documents](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/)

Comment: @JackZeng thanks, I think that's the thing I was missing.  B2C looks like the solution.